# css is not working with bootstrap less

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, less

I want to set the cover image on my home page. I have added following `css` code in my `less` file:

```
background: url("../images/default-bg2.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 / 100% 100% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

How can I set a responsive cover image?

**Note:** I am using **bootstrap less**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try

```
background: url(../images/default-bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

more information
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: When I scroll on browser the image is also scrolling on internet explorer. I don't want this scrolling image

Comment: If I got your question right ... this would be the solution 
    background-attachment:fixed;

Comment: it work. I just changed background `fixed` to `scroll`

Answer (score 0):

adding `"background-size:cover;"` to the css should work.

Please try this:

background: url("youimage.png") no-repeat center center fixed;

-webkit-background-size: 100% auto;

-moz-background-size: 100% auto;

-o-background-size: 100% auto;

background-size: 100% auto;

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url("../images/default-bg2.jpg") repeat scroll;
background-position:100% 100%;
```

Please try this.